# Rebase the same branch from origin (git rebase origin/<same?>)

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm on the local `dev` branch and want to rebase from the same branch on `origin`. This currently works:

```
git rebase origin/dev
```

Is there a way to avoid specifying `/dev`? Like

```
git rebase origin/<same>
```

This would just be to avoid rebasing the wrong branch by mistake and to create a reusable command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what I want:

```sh
git rebase origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

If there's anything shorter, please suggest.

---

*Slightly unrelated,* but I needed this to easily fetch+rebase+push as suggested on [Don't Be Scared of git rebase](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/09/14/dont-be-scared-of-git-rebase/) by making it a single command: https://gist.github.com/bfred-it/36e50e20e7927b052372

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), if `upstream` is not specified, the upstream branch configured by the `branch.name.remote` and `branch.name.merge` options will be used.

If your upstream branch info isn't set correctly, you'll probably need to do `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/dev`. After that's set up correctly, `git rebase` should just work.

Comment: This would require prior per-branch/per-repo/per-computer setup, though, right? I was hoping for something that just works everywhere.

Comment: It's best (in my opinion) to check out branches in such a way that this is automatically set. In those cases, it does not require any additional setup. For example, when you `git checkout foobar` and `foobar` does not exist locally, but `origin/foobar` exists, git will checkout `origin/foobar` to a new local branch named `foobar` and set up tracking information automatically, from the single checkout command.